# Can't access Samba share from another Linux computer anymore

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, wpa-supplicant

It used to work but now I get a "connection refused" error. It's not server's fault because my android device can sync without a problem.  I also get system error reports concerning `wpa_supplicant`. I reinstalled it and installed all the new updates and restarted the computer but nothing changed.

It is Thunar that tells me I can't access the samba share. Here is the last part of log.nmbd:

```
[2015/02/13 16:22:04.078900,  0] ../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:873(send_udp)
  Packet send failed to 192.168.150.255(138) ERRNO=Invalid argument
[2015/02/13 16:22:04.079142,  0] ../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:873(send_udp)
  Packet send failed to 192.168.150.255(138) ERRNO=Invalid argument
[2015/02/13 16:37:47.371899,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****

  Samba name server VOSTRO is now a local master browser for workgroup HOME-DESKTOP on subnet 192.168.150.1
```

Comment: If you get a message 'Connection refused', there must be some trace on the computer refusing the connection, most probably the one hosting your share.  So could you have a look at those log files (log.smbd and log.nmbd, normally under /var/log/samba) and post them?

Comment: Ha, not allowed to make a comment... need reputation for that. Can you post the /etc/samba/smb.conf from the VOSTRO computer and the server please. Also i see there is a 15 min. laps between the last to lines of the log.nmbd (which is the netbios-name server component). Can you post those 15 min of your log.smbd as well. And look if there is any information on the server in the same two logs please (and post if necessary, ofcourse). (edit) Since it is the name-server component; can you connect by ip or via "connect to server" in thunar? Can you connect via commandline? Mount it in terminal, an

Comment: Ok, you have defined a workgroup HOME-DESKTOP.  Is it also the name defined on your client (to be found in smb.conf / [globals] / workgroup )?  Just for info: the nmbd file you added is well the one on your server or on your client?
On the other hand, wpa_supplicant error is associated with Wi-fi security?  Do you experience problem with wi-fi (eg: connected via another point of access)

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen The smb.conf on the client is pristine, no special info in it. Yes, nmbd is on the server and I don't get the wpa_supplicant errors anymore but the laptop has difficulty connecting to wireless networks, usually has to attempt twice or I have to kill nm-applet and restart it.

Comment: I used Gigolo and was able to mount the shares. Problem solved for now. The problem seems to be in Thunar's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could try gathering some more information by - for example - running `wpa_supplicant` in debug-mode.

First kill the already running process like this:
`killall wpa_supplicant`

Then run it in debug-mode like this (redirecting output to standard output and to the specified log-file):
`wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -d | tee wpa_supplicant.log`

You could also use `-dd` instead of `-d` for more verbosity.

Of course I'm assuming here `wlan0` is your wireless interface and your configuration resides in `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: The configuration file is in /etc/dbus-1/system.d. Your command gave errors on almost every line of the config file and at the end said "Failed to add interface wlan0" even though "Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant".

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse
```

Comment: Didn't work. The problem seems to be at the network (wifi) level. Although internet connection is working.